# Dojo DestroyRecursive Error on Widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm working on converting Dojo from 1.6 to 1.9 and having some problems.

Before I reinstantiate a Dojo Widget, I'm attempting to destroy it with this library function:

```
function destroyWidget(idOrNode) {
    require(["dijit/registry"], function(registry) {
        var widget;

        if (typeof idOrNode === "string") {
            widget = registry.byId(idOrNode);
        }

        logDebug(widget);
        if (widget !== undefined && widget !== null) {
            widget.destroyRecursive();
        }

    });
}
```

I can pass an ID-string or an actual node to this function and let it destroy it for me.

I call it like this:

```
destroyWidget(myGrid);
myGrid = new EnhancedGrid({
              id: 'myGrid',
              store: myStore,
              structure: layout,
              plugins: {
                filter: true,
                pagination: {sizeSwitch: false},
                printer: true
              }
            },
            document.createElement('div'));
          dom.byId("divForGrid").appendChild(myGrid.domNode);
          myGrid.startup();
```

My "logDebug" shows the node as being an actual widget, but the following error is thrown:
**"TypeError: Cannot call method 'destroy' of null**

So, I guess some child of my widget has already been destroyed. Can this be because of some sync issues? As in that the node trying to be destroyed has been reinstantiated already?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My only guess here is that you already destroyed the grid by calling the destroyRecursive for a parent widget. can you give us more details  .

Answer (score 1):

You are passing parameter myGrid before assign any values to it. 
If you dry run your code you will see that first you call destroy function then create grid and assign it to myGrid.

*Suppose we run code first time then, 
on 1st step destroy function will call and search for myGrid node but no value is assign to it as a result it will show error.*

To fix this you may add an condition on destroy function as follow:

```
if(registry.byId("divForGrid")){
    destroyWidget(myGrid);
}
```

I hope this will help you.